# tmux run clears screen and prints. How to change behavior to next line

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to capture the current pane in a variable. But, `tmux run "#{pane_id}"` overrides the current pane with the command output, and then clears it after I hit a key. My remote machine prints the same command output to the next line of the pane. How do I change the behavior so my local machine prints to the next line?

I'm trying to just capture the command output in a variable so I can change pane switching behavior depending on the pane number.

Terminal prior to command:
[image]

Terminal after command: [image]

After hitting a key I return to the terminal prior to the command.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to execute the pane id itself, you want to execute a command that outputs the pane id.

e.g.

```
$ var=$(tmux run "printf '%s' '#{pane_id}'")
$ echo "$var"
%2
```

Comment: Thanks. That gets rid of the error code. But, I'm still printing to a separate pane. Let me add a screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not addressing the title; I'm not trying to fix your `tmux run …` (compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)). I'm addressing what seems to be your actual problem:

> I'm trying to just capture the command output in a variable so I can change pane switching behavior depending on the pane number.

A process running in a pane should already have `TMUX_PANE` in its environment. Examples: `echo "$TMUX_PANE"`, `env | grep TMUX`. This means a shell script in a pane can use `$TMUX_PANE` directly as a variable. I'm not sure if you want to get the ID in the pane itself or elsewhere though.

A more general way is:

```
tmux display-message -p '#{pane_id}'
```

and you can capture this to a shell variable with:

```
var="$(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_id}')"
```

The advantages are:

- The command works in a shell outside tmux (where you obviously cannot use `$TMUX_PANE`).
- Works if inside tmux, yet not in a pane (e.g. <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>`display-message '#{pane_id}'`<kbd>Enter</kbd>; the default <kbd>prefix</kbd> is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>). This includes code (possibly shell code) you may want to run upon a keystroke (`tmux bind-key …`).
- `display-message` accepts `-t`, so even in a pane you are not limited to the ID of the pane itself. Example: `tmux display-message -p -t '{bottom}' '#{pane_id}'`. See `man 1 tmux` [where it describes *target-pane*](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#Token%7E2).

Comment: That does fix my ability to use the `#{pane_id}' in a variable. I'm still getting an issue where the command prints to a temporary pane. I've solved this before by passing quiet flags for other commands. But, my remote tmux session doesn't have the same behavior.